# How can i prevent my Currency converter app from crashing when button is pressed?

Tags: java, android

I have an app for converting currency and it works when a value is entered for the dollar amount however if the user doesnt enter any value into the textview and then presses the button it crashes
what can i do so that it 1. it doesnt crash
and 2. it tells the user via toast message that no value has been entered

here is my code

```
package com.example.user.currencyconverter;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public void convert(View view) {

    EditText dollarfield = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dollarfield);

        Double dollarAmount = Double.parseDouble(dollarfield.getText().toString());

        Double poundAmount = dollarAmount * 0.7;

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), poundAmount.toString() + "Pounds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}




@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }
}
```

Comment: did my solution worked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    if (dollarfield.getText().toString().equals(""))
    {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "no value has been entered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
    else
    {
Double dollarAmount = Double.parseDouble(dollarfield.getText().toString());

            Double poundAmount = dollarAmount * 0.7;

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), poundAmount.toString() + "Pounds", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: thats what logcat says

Comment: so it cant run onClick method?

Comment: it doesnt work actually when i enter a number now it still says no value entered

Comment: anytime i press the button